# Outer measure is compatible with elementary measure

Tags: real-analysis, probability, measure-theory

This is Exercise 15 from Tao's note:https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2015/10/12/275a-notes-2-product-measures-and-independence/comment-page-2/#comment-682000

Consider the measurable space $[0,1]^A$ with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra. For any finite $B \subset A$, let ${\mu_B}$ be a probability measure on ${[0,1]^B}$ (with the Borel ${\sigma}$-algebra). One can then define the elementary measure ${\mu_0(E)}$ of any elementary set ${E = \pi_B^{-1}(E_B)}$ in ${[0,1]^A}$ by defining

$\displaystyle \mu_0( \pi_B^{-1}(E_B) ) := \mu_B( E_B )$

for any finite ${B \subset A}$ and any Borel ${E_B \subset [0,1]^B}$. Given any subset ${E \subset [0,1]^A}$ (not necessarily Borel), we define its outer measure ${\mu^*(E)}$ to be the quantity

$\displaystyle \mu^*(E) := \inf \{ \sum_{i=1}^\infty \mu_0(E_i): E_i \hbox{ open elementary cover of } E \}$.

**Question**: If ${E}$ is an elementary set, show that ${\mu^*(E) = \mu_0(E)}$. (Hint: first establish the claim when ${E}$ is compact, relying heavily on the regularity properties of the ${\mu_B}$, then extend to the general case by further heavy reliance on regularity.) One source of my confusion concerns the simple fact that a compact set is elementary by this definition, namely, if $E \subset [0,1]^A$ is compact, how to find the Borel $E_B \subset [0, 1]^B$ such that $E = \pi_B^{-1}(E_B)$ for some finite $B \subset A$, where $\pi_B$ is the projection map onto $[0,1]^B$.

Comment: What is $[0,1]^A$?

Comment: @copper.hat: It is the product space taken over the index set $A$. See also the paragraph after Remark 6 provided in the link above.