# One definition of elementary sets

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

For a collection of measurable spaces ${(\Omega_i, {\mathcal F}_i)}$ for ${i \in A}$, where ${A}$ can be infinite or even uncountable, the product ${\sigma}$-algebra ${{\mathcal F}_A := \prod_{i \in A} {\mathcal F}_i}$ on ${\Omega_A := \prod_{i \in A} \Omega_i}$ is defined to be the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the collection ${{\mathcal A}}$ of elementary sets, where we define an elementary set to be a subset of ${\Omega_A}$ of the form ${\pi_B^{-1}(E_B)}$, $B \subset A$ finite, ${\pi_B: \Omega_A \rightarrow \Omega_B}$ is the obvious projection map to ${\Omega_B := \prod_{i \in B} \Omega_i}$, and ${E_B}$ is a measurable set in ${{\mathcal F}_B := \prod_{i \in B} {\mathcal F}_i}$.

Based on this definition, an elementary set of the space $[0, 1]^A$ with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra is a set ${E = \pi_B^{-1}(E_B)}$ for any finite ${B \subset A}$ and any Borel ${E_B \subset [0,1]^B}$. But I fail to see why a compact set (say) can be elementary.

Comment: As you pointed out, the answer I proposed was wrong. Where does that statement come from? [Tychonoff's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tychonoff%27s_theorem) implies that $[0,1/2]^A$ is compact, yet it is not elementary. Are you sure about the statement? What did I miss?

Comment: I apologize for the lack of context. The question arose from my attempt to solve part 4 of Exercise 15 in Tao’s note:  https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2015/10/12/275a-notes-2-product-measures-and-independence/comment-page-2/#comment-682000. Relevant definitions can be found below Remark 6. Also, now I see that the hint for that part of the Exercise suggests not that ALL compact sets are elementary, but rather that we consider those elementary sets which are compact.

Comment: I see. I suggest you should rewrite the question, because 1) the way it is currently phrased, you are asking to prove a false statement, and 2) it seems a bit far from your real question about outer measures. I would be happy to help but unfortunately I do not have enough time to look at the document, understand the real question and answer it. The lack of answer from other people makes me believe it would be a good idea to rewrite the question and make it more clear for everyone.

Comment: @Will: The last sentence of the question is now rephrased to ask for an example(rather than proving a universal statement). For the original question, see my original post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4790320/outer-measure-is-compatible-with-elementary-measure

Comment: $[0,1]^A$ itself is compact and elementary. You can find plenty examples with Tychonoff's theorem in mind: any product of compact spaces is itself compact.

Comment: @Will: We're not considering $[0,1]^A$ in the relative topology here, for otherwise the concept of an open elementary set won't make sense since every such set $\mu_B^{-1}(E_B)$ will contain a closed interval $[0,1]$ as its' component.

Comment: I am not sure to understand what you mean. Are you saying an open set cannot be elementary? Yes they can, and the set of elementary open sets is even by definition the basis of the product topology on $[0,1]^A$ (in the same spirit of the definition of the product $\sigma$-algebra). $[0,1]$ is closed but also open in itself so it's fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149268/discussion-between-kk-slider-and-will).

Comment: @Will: Yes, since $[0,1]^A$ is both open and closed, an elementary set $\pi^{-1}_B(E_B)$ is open/closed iff $E_B$ is open/closed, now I see the way to prove the original problem(elementary measure and outer measure agree on elementary sets). Thank you for your feedback.